# How do I get data from a related user in a subclass of ParseObject?

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, parse-platform

I'm working in VisualStudio on a Xamarin project.

I have a ParseObject subclass. It has a field "SentBy" that links to a ParseUser. It's constructed like this:

```
[ParseClassName("Beacon")]
public class Stuff_ParseBeacon : ParseObject
{
    public Stuff_ParseBeacon() {  }
    
    [ParseFieldName("sentBy")]
    public ParseUser SentBy
    {
        get { return GetProperty<ParseUser>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value);}
    }
}
```

I'm trying to include a parameter that doesn't need to be in the ParseClass on the server, which gets the data stored under "phoneNumber" from the linked user. So, like this:

```
    public string SentByPhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return SentBy.Get<string>("phoneNumber");
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting the error that there's no such key in that ParseUser--which is false, because all my ParseUsers store a phone number.

What am I doing wrong?

(BTW, in case it matters: I'm trying to use SentByPhoneNumber as a bindable property)

Comment: What tutorial are you trying to follow? Is there a reason you're not using Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: I'm not following any tutorial, I'm coding in Xamarin.Forms and c#.

Comment: It's a lot easier if you use Newtonsoft.Json, as you can see in this example https://github.com/saamerm/Xamarin-GoogleSheetsDB/blob/master/XamarinGoogleSheetsDB/MainPage.xaml.cs You can then paste the json date to this website to get the C# that goes in the model https://json2csharp.com

Comment: I agree with @Saamer, it seems like your code is overly complicated and the issue could be resolved easier with Newtonsoft.Json functionality (or the System.Text.Json one).

Comment: Everybody’s got their favored APIs, and unless I misunderstand, you’re trying to get me to use yours, but I’m not wading into that argument. I totally believe the code may be over-complicated, but there’s no way around using Parse objects. If you know a simpler way to do it while still using a ParseObject subclass, I’m all ears, but rewriting all the database code and push notification system isn’t an option. If I’m misunderstanding and there’s some way to use Newtonsoft.json alongside the Parse object, please let me know.

Comment: Could you provide the code of class `ParseUser ` ?

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#users

Comment: By default, the User class is protected and you can only retrieve other users (that not the current logged in one) using the master key. So you will probably have to create a cloud code function to retrieve the Beacon objects together with the user information using `query.include(sentBy)`. Another option can be a beforeQuery/afterQuery trigger to include this information by default.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo it seems like it can't get users but it can query them?

Comment: Only from cloud code using the userMasterKey option.

Comment: Huh, I seem to have it working without a master key or any cloud code at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way to do it, but this is what I ended up doing.

I just added a `phoneNumber` field to the Beacon class, and it gets directly filled by the user who creates the Beacon--the user who gets stored in the `SentBy` field.

The problem with this is that the won't automatically update if I change the phoneNumber on the `SentBy` user.

This is pretty much exactly what I didn't want to do in my question.

So I'm sure there's a better way to refer to a field on a stored user than manually putting that data in the referring class at the time of creation, but it's what I've had to do to move on.